# Submit Jade form

Tags: node.js, pug, form-submit

What is the error with the following Jade form template? I can't get it to submit values.

```
 div
   form(action='/signup',method='post')
     div(data-role='fieldcontain')
       fieldset(data-role='controlgroup')
         label(for='email') email
         input(id='email',type='text',value='',placeholder='@')
     div#passworddiv(data-role='fieldcontain')
       fieldset(data-role='controlgroup
         label(for='password') password
         input(id='password',type='password',value='',placeholder='')
     div(id='hiddendiv',data-role='fieldcontain')
       fieldset(data-role='controlgroup')
         label(for='hidden_password') password
         input(id='hidden_password',type='text',value='',placeholder='')
     div(data-role='fieldcontain')
       fieldset(data-type='vertical',    data-role='controlgroup') 
         label(for='showpass') show password
         input(id='showpass',type='checkbox')
     div(data-role='fieldcontain')   
       input(type='submit',value='Sign Up',data-transition='fade', data-theme='c')
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The problem is because you haven't given any of the input fields a name.

```
app.post('/signup', function(req,res){
  console.log(req.body);
})
```

Returns:
`{}`

If you edit the form to the following:

```
 div
  form(action='/signup',method='post')
    div(data-role='fieldcontain')
      fieldset(data-role='controlgroup')
        label(for='email') email
           input(id='email',type='text',value='',placeholder='@',name='email')
    div#passworddiv(data-role='fieldcontain')
      fieldset(data-role='controlgroup')
        label(for='password') password
           input(id='password',type='password',value='',placeholder='',name='password')
    div(id='hiddendiv',data-role='fieldcontain')
      fieldset(data-role='controlgroup')
        label(for='hidden_password') password
           input(id='hidden_password',type='text',value='',placeholder='',name='password2')
    div(data-role='fieldcontain')
      fieldset(data-type='vertical', data-role='controlgroup')                                           
       label(for='showpass') show password
       input(id='showpass',type='checkbox')
    div(data-role='fieldcontain')   
      input(type='submit',value='Sign Up',data-transition='fade', data-theme='c')
```

After entering some data,

```
app.post('/signup', function(req,res){
  console.log(req.body);
})
```

returns:

```
{ email: 'testing@fake.com',
  password: 'asdf',
  password2: 'asdf' }
```