# How to create posts requests with express.js , mongoose and jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, pug

The below code is from a tutorial I'm doing. I want to know how to capture and respond to post requests. I thought this would be easy to understand but the problem is as follows.

First here is the code:

**Node**

```
app.post('/tasks', function(req, res){
  var task = new Task(req.body.task);   // This line 
  task.save(function (err) {
    if (!err) {
      res.redirect('/tasks/new');
    }
    else {
      throw err;
    }
  });
});
```

**Jade**

```
extends ../layout

block content
  h1 New task view

  form(role='form', method='post', action='/tasks')
    fieldset
      legend Add a task
      div.form-group
        label Task
        input(name='task[task]', class='form-control')  // This line
      button.btn.btn-primary(type='submit') Submit
      button.btn.btn-default(type='reset') Clear
```

**Mongoose**

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/todo_development');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var Task = new Schema({
  task: { type: String, required: true }
});

var Task = mongoose.model('Task', Task);
```

In the first two blocks of code above each has a comment called 'this line'.  Within these lines are the word **task** as attributes/properties. When I change these to something else like 'oink' it breaks the code.

So for example if I do:

**node**

```
  var task = new Task(req.body.oink);   // This line
```

**jade**

```
input(name='oink[oink]', class='form-control')  // This line
```

It no worky.
I am not sure why nor how to do posts requests correctly. :(

Comment: maybe use `input(name='oink')`? I don't see why you repeating it in square brackets

Comment: Its the way the tutorial was written. It came like that with the book. I figured it might be a jade convention or something. Your idea doesn't work. I get an error. 500 TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '_id' in adf

Comment: I figured it out the brackets references the task object in the schema

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line

```
var task = new Task(req.body.task);
```

To this:

```
var task = new Task(req.body);
```

I'm not very familiar with Jade, but as far as I can tell from [Submit Jade form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10151837/submit-jade-form) you should name your input like...

```
input(id='password',type='password',value='',placeholder='',name='password')
```

Also, what does your mongoose schema look like? That may be helpful.

You have defined the variable "Task" twice. Try this...

```
var taskSchema = new Schema({
  task: { type: String, required: true }
});

var Task = mongoose.model('Task', taskSchema);
```

Comment: Seems like the root of your issue is the naming of your input. See edit.

Comment: I added the mongoose schema

Comment: I figured it out the  [task] references the schema innards

Answer (score 0):

put:
input(name='task[]', class='form-control')  // This line

and put this:
var task = new Task({'task':req.body.task});   // This line

luck

Comment: Can you expand upon what you did above to explain the changes?

Comment: In the jade file the name "task" is called to node file but the name into [ ] is like a variable in node file, i don't know why don't work your code but the other way is how i put it. not send the name of variable int [ ], create the variable i node file: {'task':req.body.task}.                                                       pdt: I think the trouble is for the constructor "proto". Sorry for the english.