# Express 4: POST method

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, http, pug

I'm building an application using Express 4. I'm trying to get some data out of a form, but it always returns empty `{}`

I have the following lines in **app.js**:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var signup = require('./routes/signup');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use('/signup', signup);
```

My route handler, **signup.js**:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// signup routing handler
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('signup');
});
router.post('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));
    res.send('Foo Bar!');
});

module.exports = router;
```

My form, in Jade format:

```
form.form-horizontal(method='post')
    .form-group
        label.col-sm-2.control-label(for='firstName') 
            | First Name:
                .col-sm-10
                    input.form-control( #firstName, type='text', placeholder='John')
    .form-group
        .col-sm-2.control-label
            button.btn.btn-default(type='submit')
                        | Sign Up!
```

Comment: you need to give names to the input fields.  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10151837/submit-jade-form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inputs in the Jade file need names in order to have keys in the JSON

Like this:

```
form.form-horizontal(method='post')
.form-group
    label.col-sm-2.control-label(for='firstName') 
        | First Name:
            .col-sm-10
                input.form-control( #firstName, 
                                    type='text', 
                                    placeholder='John', 
                                    name='firstName')
.form-group
    .col-sm-2.control-label
        button.btn.btn-default(type='submit')
                    | Sign Up!
```